# GPO Wireless Settings - Trusted Root CA

Tags: authentication, certificate, wifi

We pushed SSID configuration by GPO. Computer configuration > Policies > Security Settings > Wireless Network Policies.

In these settings we enabled certificate authentication, however the root CA isn't checked on Network authentication method properties.

How do computers validate or trust the certificate that is presented by the network device?

Does Windows look for the corresponding root CA in the computer certificate store?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding your post. But in your wireless profile you can specify in multiple places what servers to trust and/or what certificate issuers to trust. The radius server presents a certificate that should be signed by a “trusted issuer” that you selected and with the server name you enter.

Answer (score 0):

`Does Windows look for the corresponding root CA in the computer certificate store?`

Windows does indeed check the local computer root CA store. Management of the stores can be enhanced and supplemented by Group Policy.

Additionally, updated *public* root CA certificates for Microsoft Root CA Program participants may also be downloaded by using `certutil`, and placed on a network share, where Group Policy clients can be configured to pull updated certificates from a centrally managed administrative share.

Note that by default, Windows attempts to automatically update the CTL of the program participants directly from Microsoft on a periodic basis.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-cs/certificate-trust

Answer (score 0):

The CA needs to "enroll" client certificates to the clients that need to authenticate. The validation is usually done by the network device who contacts the root ca with the client certificate and tries to match that against issued certificates,issued by the CA.

There could also be a network policy server in between who authenticates/authorizes the user against Active Directory and validates the certificate.
https://www.risual.com/2018/08/configuring-certificate-authentication-for-a-wireless-network/